# Class doesn't contain member definition error for a member previously removed from the solution?

Tags: c#

I am running into an issue where I am getting an error while running my code. The error is "VariableManager.characteristicPoints    'AmericanPresident.VariableManager' does not contain a definition for 'characteristicPoints'".

I get this error when the InfluencePointManager method calls UpdateInfluencePoints or the UpdateOriginalPoints in the VariableManager class. I've attempted cleaning the solution as well as deleting the bin and obj folders. Also I searched the entire solution for "characteristicPoints" and it's no where to be found anymore. I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AmericanPresident
{
    class InfluencePointManager
    {
        public enum Influence
        {
            homeland,
            military,
            political,
            economic,
            legal,
            criminal,
            numberOfInfluenceItems
        }
        private int[] _originalPoints = new int[(int)Influence.numberOfInfluenceItems];
        private static int[] _influencePoints = new int[(int)Influence.numberOfInfluenceItems];

        public int[] InitialPointDistribution()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int i = 0, j, k = 0;

            foreach (int l in _originalPoints)
            {
                _originalPoints[k] = 0;
                k++;
                if (k < 6)
                {
                    Console.Write(_originalPoints[k]);
                };
            }

            do
            {
                j = rand.Next(6);
                Console.Write(j);

                switch (j)
                {
                    case (int)Influence.homeland:
                        if (_originalPoints[(int)Influence.homeland] != 10)
                        {
                            _originalPoints[(int)Influence.homeland]++;
                            i++;
                            Console.Write(_originalPoints[(int)Influence.homeland]);
                            break;
                        }
                        else break;
                    case (int)Influence.military:
                        if (_originalPoints[(int)Influence.military] != 10)
                        {
                            _originalPoints[(int)Influence.military]++;
                            i++;
                            Console.Write(_originalPoints[(int)Influence.military]);
                            break;
                        }
                        else break;
                    case (int)Influence.political:
                        if (_originalPoints[(int)Influence.political] != 10)
                        {
                            _originalPoints[(int)Influence.political]++;
                            i++;
                            Console.Write(_originalPoints[(int)Influence.political]);
                            break;
                        }
                        else break;
                    case (int)Influence.economic:
                        if (_originalPoints[(int)Influence.economic] != 10)
                        {
                            _originalPoints[(int)Influence.economic]++;
                            i++;
                            Console.Write(_originalPoints[(int)Influence.economic]);
                            break;
                        }
                        else break;
                    case (int)Influence.legal:
                        if (_originalPoints[(int)Influence.legal] != 10)
                        {
                            _originalPoints[(int)Influence.legal]++;
                            i++;
                            Console.Write(_originalPoints[(int)Influence.legal]);
                            break;
                        }
                        else break;
                    case (int)Influence.criminal:
                        if (_originalPoints[(int)Influence.criminal] != 10)
                        {
                            _originalPoints[(int)Influence.criminal]++;
                            i++;
                            Console.Write(_originalPoints[(int)Influence.criminal]);
                            break;
                        }
                        else break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            } while (i < 18);

            //the next line s where the error occurs
            VariableManager.VariableManagerInstance.UpdateOriginalPoints(_originalPoints, this);
            VariableManager.VariableManagerInstance.UpdateInfluencePoints(_originalPoints, this);
            return _influencePoints;
        }
}
```

This is the other class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AmericanPresident
{
    class VariableManager
    {
        private static VariableManager variableManagerInstance;
    private VariableManager() { }

    public static VariableManager VariableManagerInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (variableManagerInstance == null)
            {
                variableManagerInstance = new VariableManager();
            }
            return variableManagerInstance;
        }
    }

    public string playerName { get; private set; }

    public int[] experiencePoints { get; private set;}

    public int[] resources { get; private set; }

    public int[] originalPoints { get; private set; }

    public int[] influencePoints { get; private set; }

    public StartPage startPage { get; private set; }

    public int availableInfluencePonts { get; private set; }

    public void UpdatePlayerName(string name, object o)
    {
        if(o is CharacterBuildManager)
        {
            playerName = name;
        }
    }
//error occurs when the either of the next to methods are called by the
//InfluencePointManager
    public void UpdateInfluencePoints(int[] p, object o)
    {
        if(o is InfluencePointManager)
        {
            p.CopyTo(influencePoints,0);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateOriginalPoints(int[] p, object o)
    {
        if(o is InfluencePointManager)
        {
            p.CopyTo(originalPoints, 0);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateStartPage(StartPage sp, object o)
    {
        if(o is StartPage)
        {
            startPage = sp;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateAvailableInfluencePoints(int i, object o)
    {
        if(o is InfluencePointManager)
        {
            availableInfluencePonts = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried closing the solution and re-opening it?  I've never heard of an error throwing on non-existent code after a clean and build.

Comment: Yes. Because the solution wasn't very larger I created a new version of it and copied the code over. I ran it in the new solution. I got an error in the same place. The error I was getting above really threw me off to what is going on.

Comment: Basically what is happening is that I am trying to send a private array over to another class then attempting to invoke one of it's methods in the other class. Of course the program is not actually allowing me to access a private member in a class for which it does not belong so p is null in the VariableManager class. I couldn't see this till I ran the new solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no clue why the solution was referencing a member that no longer existed. I tested the code in a new solution which helped me identify the problem.

Basically what is happening is that my array are null. I added this code to the methods in VariableManager which resolved the issue.

```
if(originalPoints == null)
        {
            originalPoints = new int[(int)InfluencePointManager.Influence.numberOfInfluenceItems];
        }
```

Very odd error still so I guess this is only partially solved.